# Angular using JSON Data from API Call

Tags: angular, typescript

I get following JSON Data from a back-end webservice.

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "My Name1",
        "age": 25,
        "jsonData": null
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "My Name2",
        "age": 25,
        "jsonData": "{\"Address\":\"My Address 123\",\"City\":\"My City\",\"PostalCode\":\"ABC-123-DEF\",\"Country\":\"My Country\"}"
    }
]
```

I can loop the array on component html with ngFor without problem, but how do I read the "jsonData" fields like "Address", "City" etc.?

**Thank you for the answer!**

my API call from component.ts is like this:

```
async getAllUsers() {
    this.allUsers = [];

    this.allUsers = await lastValueFrom(
        await this.service.getAllUsers()
    );

    this.allUsers.forEach((node) => {
        node.jsonData = JSON.parse(node.jsonData);
    });
}
```

then in my html I do like this:

```
{{ node.jsonData.Address }}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `JSON.parse(jsonData)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `jsonData` from `string` to object type with `JSON.parse(<JSON string>)`.

Note that this can be performed during the returning `Observable`/response via the `map` (RxJS) operator.

Note that your `jsonData` is possibly `null`, so you have to check the `jsonData` is truthy before converting.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs';

this.http.get<any[]>('<API URL>').pipe(
  map((resp: any[]) =>
    resp.map((x: any) => ({
      ...x,
      jsonData: !!x.jsonData ? JSON.parse(x.jsonData) : null,
    }))
  )
);
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hcybav?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.parse() for the stringified json object. Use JSON.parse in a try catch block so that if the passsed jsonData has format issue, you can catch it and take necessary steps from inside the catch block.

If you use Rxjs, try using [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator in order to map the response to the specific format you want. @Yong Shun has already shown the way for you. You can try [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) from rxjs in order to handle any error more elegantly from your observable chain.